# Can anyone tell me the meaning of these sentences?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> 1. I don't plan on **face planting** tonight.
> 2. in other words, someone who would totally **slay** at Bend A Friend.

Does *slay* in the second sentence seriously mean like *kill*?

Comment: *Face plant* literally means to land on one's face, so figuratively it means to fail spectacularly; *slay* and *kill* are US slang terms in show business, particularly in comedic acts. They mean to be extremely successful.

Answer (score 1):

"I don't plan on face planting tonight,” Face planting refers to falling on one's face. If someone does not plan on face planting they don't plan on falling on their face/embarrassing themselves or making a big mistake.

In the second sentence slay means to do better than anyone else. It does mean to kill but not physically. It's like to kill the competition/ to win over them. When someone says they are slaying or someone else is slaying it means that they are doing better (killing) then everyone else.